# get last $var in a 'while' statement, php?

Tags: php

I am running a loop that ticks a counter.

Basically, it's

```
<counter>
<a php form>
```

the counter is pulling objects from a database. If there are 10 or more objects pulled, I want the form to be shut off. I'm not sure how to pull the counter out of the 'while' statement though?

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;

    //LOOPING CODE IS HERE
    example: ---- 'while ( $var->this() ) : $var->that();'----------

    // Add to counter
    $counter = ++$counter;

    // Cleanup after ourselves
    endwhile;
?>
```

now after the `endwhile;` I need to be able to call the last value of `$counter` and determine it was = or > 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is

```
$counter = 0;
while(condition is true)
{
   //increment $counter
   if($counter >= 10)
     break;  //break out of the loop
}

print($counter);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could break the while loop when the counter has exceeded 10, and then you still have `$counter` for use.

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    while ($var->this() && $counter < 10) {
        $var->that();
        $counter++;
    }
    echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: Though this works, it's stylistically a little funny: when using `while` loops, `break`is the expected syntax. I'm absolutely not saying there's anything wrong with your method if it's used consistently, though!

Comment: It's stylistically funny to have an if-break with the condition related to only a variable with a scope encompassing the entire while loop.

Comment: I do see where this would be useful, unfortunately the other answer works best for my particular scenario. +1 for teaching a new way (that  does work as well)

Comment: I agree with Vulcan.  The `while` conditional should serve the purpose of continuing the loop until it should be terminated.  If a clear termination condition exists (that is, the logic is not too complex), then it makes sense to place it in the `while` condition.

Comment: That's fair. I guess I should amend my comment to "That works but it looks weird to me because I'm anal-retentive." :)